# How to automatically retrieve string values from two Text Views, sum them up and display as value of double in another Text view

Tags: android

I have 2 edit text fields, num1a & num1b where the result is automatically displayed in textViewResult1. likewise; I have another 2 edit text fields, num2a & num2b where the result is automatically displayed in textViewResult2; For me its a learning process to code hence how to set the sum of textViewResult1 & textViewResult2 in textViewGrandTotal.

```
   package com.app.learn3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText num1a, num1b;
    TextView textViewResult1;
    EditText num2a, num2b;
    TextView textViewResult2;
    TextView textViewGrandTotal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        num1a = findViewById(R.id.editText1a);
        num1b = findViewById(R.id.editText1b);
        textViewResult1 = findViewById(R.id.textView_result_1);

        num2a = findViewById(R.id.editText2a);
        num2b = findViewById(R.id.editText2b);
        textViewResult2 = findViewById(R.id.textView_result_2);

        textViewGrandTotal = findViewById(R.id.textView_GrandTotal);

        num1a.addTextChangedListener(numTextWatcher);
        num1b.addTextChangedListener(numTextWatcher);
        num2a.addTextChangedListener(numTextWatcher);
        num2b.addTextChangedListener(numTextWatcher);

    }

    private TextWatcher numTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            textViewResult1.setText(total_1());
            textViewResult2.setText(total_2());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };

    private String total_1() {
        double number1;
        int number2;
        if (num1a.getText().toString() != "" && num1a.getText().length() > 0) {
            number1 = Double.parseDouble(num1a.getText().toString());
        } else {
            number1 = 0;
        }
        if (num1b.getText().toString() != "" && num1b.getText().length() > 0) {
            number2 = Integer.parseInt(num1b.getText().toString());
        } else {
            number2 = 0;
        }
        String calc1 = new DecimalFormat("0.000").format(number1 * number2);
        return Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(calc1));
    }

    private String total_2() {
        double number3;
        int number4;
        if (num2a.getText().toString() != "" && num2a.getText().length() > 0) {
            number3 = Double.parseDouble(num2a.getText().toString());
        } else {
            number3 = 0;
        }
        if (num2b.getText().toString() != "" && num2b.getText().length() > 0) {
            number4 = Integer.parseInt(num2b.getText().toString());
        } else {
            number4 = 0;
        }
        String calc2 = new DecimalFormat("0.000").format(number3 * number4);
        return Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(calc2));
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to create one single `TextWatcher` that performs all of the sums on each change, then set that one `TextWatcher` on all four `EditText`s.

Comment: Thanks mike, just updated to single TextWatcher as you suggested, yet to find out though how to get the sum total to show up in textViewGrandTotal. Suggestion are welcome.

Comment: You're nearly there. You just need to `textViewGrandTotal.setText(...);` with the sum(?) of `total_1()` and `total_2()`, however you'd like to do that. If I were to do it with the given code, I'd change the `total_*()` methods' return type to `double` instead of `String`. Then, in `onTextChanged()`, `double total1 = total_1();`, `double total2 = total_2();`, `double bigTotal = total1 + total2;`, then do `String.valueOf()` for each of the three `setText()` calls. (I'm not sure if you actually want a sum or a product.)

Comment: Hi Mike, appreciate your help. Since I am learning can you please explain how to do this part    -> do String.valueOf() for each of the three setText() calls. Thanks.

Comment: `textViewResult1.setText(String.valueOf(total1));`, `textViewResult2.setText(String.valueOf(total2));`, `textViewGrandTotal.setText(String.valueOf(bigTotal));`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
       @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { 
    textViewResult1.setText(total_1());
     textViewResult2.setText(total_2()); 
  textViewGrandTotal.setText(String.valueOf (grandTotal());
        }

    private Double grandTotal(){
    Double total=Double.parseDouble(total_1())+Double.parseDouble(total_2());
return total;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it, but it say private method grandTotal() is never used and the app is same as before, meaning no sum result is displayed at textViewGrandTotal.

Comment: Call this function below textViewResult2.setText(total_2()) and textViewResult1.setText(total_1())

Comment: Thanks pradeep for your suggestions, yet I did not get it right. Kindly go through the updated code, from multiple TextWatcher Listener to single as been suggested by mike. One more point, your code says ....valueOf(Integer.parseInt(.....  Will that work with double?

Comment: Modify code like.   textViewResult1.setText(total_1()); textViewResult2.setText(total_2());.                                  grandTotal();.                                                       For double you can use Double.parDouble() instead of Integer.parseInt()